# nested attributes using reject_if not working after render

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I have a form with nested attributes and my model code contains:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :current_skills, :allow_destroy => true, reject_if: lambda {|attributes| attributes['skill_id'].blank?}
```

In my controller:

```
def edit
  @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
  ...
  @employee.current_skills.build
  @employee.desired_skills.build
end

def update
  ...
  @employee.current_skills.build
  @employee.desired_skills.build
  if @employee.update_attributes(employee_params)
    redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully updated.' 
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

In the case of a validation failure, the update, as expected, is not being saved and the edit view is being rendered. My understanding is that I need the .build methods in the update action to resupply the empty fields to the form (this is the case in my testing); however, when including the .build methods to supply the fields, they are not being rejected by the model on the second submit and are being saved to the database (not as I would expect).

Is there a better way to supply the fields after a validation failure but also have them rejected if blank?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If I were you I would do this:

```
def update
  ...
  if @employee.update_attributes(employee_params)
    redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully updated.' 
  else
    @employee.current_skills.build if @employee.current_skills.empty?
    @employee.desired_skills.build if @employee.desired_skills.empty?
    render :edit
  end
end
```

I hope it helps.

**Edit**: After read your comment, I must to say: your code is fine and it must to work. Is not standard build an association in update method, and I can't see why you need it (if is for the tests, remove from main code and work on the tests). At this point, you must check the params at the server log, or a callback in yours models that set the `skill_id` value. BTW if the record saved have an `skill_id` not nil, your `accept_nested_attributes_for` is working fine.

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately, this didn't solve my problem. I need a way to reject the blank fields provided by .build methods in the update action, not control if or when they appear. I thought the reject_if method in the model would run even when the form was resubmitted, but it seems to be skipped. Is there a difference in the way the attributes are saved if they come from a form generated by the edit action vs being generated by the update action?